# run a bash for loop in parallel

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

I've got this script that does a credential lookup for each host, in an on-premise vault system, and then runs an ansible-playbook for it.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for host in `cat ~/.ansible/hosts`
  do
    SECRET=`/opt/vault/bin/get-admin-credential --tag=$host`
    HOST=`echo $SECRET | cut -d ';' -f1`
    LOGIN=`echo $SECRET | cut -d ';' -f2`
    DOMAIN=`echo $SECRET | cut -d ';' -f3`
    PWD=`echo $SECRET | cut -d ';' -f4`

    if [ -z "$DOMAIN" ]; then
      ansible-playbook -i ~/.ansible/hosts ~/.ansible/windows.yml -e "ansible_host=$HOST ansible_user=$LOGIN ansible_password=$PWD" --limit $host
    else
      ansible-playbook -i ~/.ansible/hosts ~/.ansible/windows.yml -e "ansible_host=$HOST ansible_user=$LOGIN@$DOMAIN ansible_password=$PWD" --limit $host
    fi
  done
```

This loops over each host sequentially, I've tried stuff with GNU `parallel` but haven't been able to do what I want, running the for loop with 5 in parallel.

Anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Not familiar with ansible but (this may be a dumb question), have you tried creating a function? e.g., `function parallel_fn { for ... do ... done }` followed by `parallel_fn & parallel_fn`?

Comment: @C.Dunn I don't think that will run the 5 ansible processes in parallel with each other. Rather, it will create a loop that runs the 5 ansible processes sequentially one after the other but which runs in parallel alongside the caller of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any *"ansibles"* or *"vaults"*, so this is completely untested but may get you close:

```
doit(){
   host="$1"

   SECRET=$(/opt/vault/bin/get-admin-credential --tag=$host)
   HOST=$(echo $SECRET | cut -d ';' -f1)
   LOGIN=$(echo $SECRET | cut -d ';' -f2)
   DOMAIN=$(echo $SECRET | cut -d ';' -f3)
   PWD=$(echo $SECRET | cut -d ';' -f4)

   if [ -z "$DOMAIN" ]; then
      ansible-playbook -i ~/.ansible/hosts ~/.ansible/windows.yml -e "ansible_host=$HOST ansible_user=$LOGIN ansible_password=$PWD" --limit $host
   else
      ansible-playbook -i ~/.ansible/hosts ~/.ansible/windows.yml -e "ansible_host=$HOST ansible_user=$LOGIN@$DOMAIN ansible_password=$PWD" --limit $host
   fi
}

# Export doit function to subshells created by GNU Parallel
export -f doit

parallel -a ~/.ansible/hosts doit
```

Stylistically, there are maybe a few improvements. Firstly, shell variables consisting of upper case letters are reserved, so you shouldn't maybe use `HOST`, `DOMAIN` etc. Also, you can probably simplify all that unsightly cutting and echoing to extract the variables from the SECRET by using an `IFS=';'` and a `read` like this:

```
SECRET=$(/opt/vault/bin/get-admin-credential --tag=$host)
IFS=';' read host login domain pwd <<< "$SECRET"
```

So, my best and final answer is:

```
doit(){
   host="$1"

   secret=$(/opt/vault/bin/get-admin-credential --tag=$host)
   IFS=';' read host login domain pwd <<< "$secret"

   if [ -z "$domain" ]; then
      ansible-playbook -i ~/.ansible/hosts ~/.ansible/windows.yml -e "ansible_host=$host ansible_user=$login ansible_password=$pwd" --limit $host
   else
      ansible-playbook -i ~/.ansible/hosts ~/.ansible/windows.yml -e "ansible_host=$host ansible_user=$login@$domain ansible_password=$pwd" --limit $host
   fi
}

# Export doit function to subshells created by GNU Parallel
export -f doit

parallel -a ~/.ansible/hosts doit
```

Comment: Thanks!
I've changed the `--limit $host` into `--limit $1`. My for loop was a bit confusing with both `for host in` and then also the host variable.
Not really necessary in this case, but is it possible to combine the input source parameter with `--jobs` to limit the simultaneous runs? No matter what amount I specify it does the same with or without the parameter.

Comment: There are several useful enhancements that you could port across from @chepner answer... the `if` statement, the `-r` and trailing `_` on the `read` statement...

Comment: You should be able to use `parallel -j 4 ...` to do just 4 at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to run `ansible-playbook` in the background using the `&` command terminator. Note, though, that the entire loop can be simplified and improved.

```
run_playbook () {
  ansible-playbook -i ~/.ansible/hosts \
                   -e "ansible_host=$2 ansible_login=$3 ansible_password=$4" \
                   ~/.ansible/windows.yml --limit "$1"
}

while IFS= read -r host; do
    secret=$(/opt/vault/bin/get-admin-credential --tag="$host")
    IFS=";" read -r shost slogin sdomain spasswd _ <<< "$secret"
    if [[ -n $sdomain ]]; then
      login="$slogin@$sdomain"
    fi
    run_playbook "$host" "$shost" "$login" "$password" &
done < ~/.ansible/hosts
```

Comment: While the code here is better in many ways, it will run all the hosts it can at once, not just the 5 (at a time) requested.  I would also suggest that the ansible log output was saved to a per host log file, as as things stand all output will be intermingled very confusingly.