# Compare old vs new directory and recompress changed files

Tags: bash, sh

I run a nightly job to generate static webpages. The new files are stored in a directory `new` and the old ones are moved to a directory `old`. After generating the pages I run:

```
find new -type f -name "*.html" -exec zopfli {} \;
```

`zopfli` offers better gzip compression results but is more CPU intensive. Because we are talking about some 30,000 pages this is a problem. It takes 6 hours to compress them all.

Luckily less than 1% of all static pages actually change. So I don't have to recompress them all. I could just mv the old `.gz` files form the `old` directory to the `new` directory. To see if a file has changed it would be good enough to compare the file size of the `.html` files (`old` vs. `new` director). If it has changed it would have to be compressed. Sometimes files get deleted or new files generated which are not in the `old` directory.

```
├── new
│   ├── a
│   │   ├── test.html
│   │   └── test2.html
│   ├── b
│   │   └── test.html
│   └── index.html
└── old
    ├── a
    │   ├── test2.html
    │   └── test2.html.gz
    ├── b
    │   ├── test.html
    │   └── test.html.gz
    ├── index.html
    └── index.html.gz
```

I can do this with Ruby or Perl. But I would like to do it with a Bash shell script. Is that possible? How can I do it?

Comment: Look into `rsync` or version control with `git`.

Comment: `rsync` doesn't work here. Because `rsync` doesn't know that the original `.html` and the `.html.gz` file are connected. Same problem with `git`.

Comment: Er... You wouldn't bother with that compression step. Rebuild the master tree of html files, and use rsync to update the remote tree with the changes. Or commit changes + pull on the remote end for a git-managed tree.

Comment: If you really want compressed files for some reason, you could probably set up a hook in git to automatically do it on committing changed files.

Comment: Can't you compare the timestamps and write a make rule? I would remove `old` directory, it's going to duplicate a lot of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `cmp` to compare files:

```
find new -name '*.html' -exec sh -c '
  for f; do
    if cmp -s "$f" "old/${f#*/}"; then
      echo cp "old/${f#*/}.gz" "${f%/*}"
    else
      echo zopfli "$f"
    fi
  done' _ {} +
```

If its output looks good remove `echo`s.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using **GNU Parallel** to zip in parallel:

```
find new -type f -name "*.html" -print0 | parallel -0 zopfli
```

By default, it will run one job for each CPU core you have, but you can change that with `parallel -j 8` to run, say 8, jobs in parallel.

Use `parallel --bar` or `parallel --eta` for a progress bar or *"Estimated Time of Arrival"*.

Consider putting old and new filesystems on different disks, to reduce contention.

Comment: I actually do that right now. But I would like to not do the unnecessary work at all.

Comment: Ok, you could run a function under `parallel` that compares the file sizes/times before compressing if you wanted to like this... https://stackoverflow.com/a/60850814/2836621

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest to remove `old` directory and find new files to compress using modification timestamps. You could use `make`:

```
# Makefile
.SUFFIXES:
htmls=$(shell find new -type f -name '*.html')
gzips=${htmls:%.html=%.html.gz}
all: ${gzips} cleanup
%.html.gz: %.html
        echo zopfli $^
cleanup:
        @# find all .html.gz files without .html files and remove them
        find new -type f -name '*.html.gz' \
        -exec bash -c '[[ ! -e "${1%.gz}" ]]' _ {} \; \
        -delete
        # or -exec sh -c '[ ! -e "$(basename "$1" .gz)" ]'
```

With `find` that would be:

```
find new -type f -name '*.html' -exec bash -c '[[ ! -e "$1".gz || "$1" -nt "$1".gz ]]' _ {} \; -exec echo zopfli {} +
```

Comment: Wrt your second proposal; spawning a bash instance for each and every file is a waste of time and resources; all modern versions of find have bulk-exec primary, which with a simple loop could reduce the number of shells spawned from 1:1 to 4k:1. Or, since you use bash for a mere conditional expression, you can use coreutil's `test` like `-exec test '!' -e {}.gz -o {} -nt {}.gz \;` instead and reduce the amount of memory and CPU time used for testing.

Comment: I think `{}.gz` is not posix. That is the reason I use `bash ... {}`

Comment: Yes, it's unspecified. That's why I suggested using a loop first.